# How to transfer more than 50 GB database from local database to server database

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql database. It has more than 50 GB of data what will be the easiest way of transferring it from local database to server database

Answer (score 1):

Dump -> Zip -> Copy to server -> Unzip  -> Import